# Cómo ejecutar varios ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, asp, sweetalert2

`introducir el código aquí`hace instantes me una al grupo con una duda existencial. Estoy utilizando los `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` para ejecutar funciones javascripts de sweetalert2 en una pagina asp.net con VB.

Mi único problema es que solo me ejecuta la ultima función que tengo en mi código y cuando debugeo nuestra el transcurso normal del código, tengo el claro el tema de que las funciones javascript se ejecutan después de haber leído todo el código ya que el registerStartupscript funciona así.

si alguien alguien puede darme una mano con alguna solución para poder mostrar cada uno de mis sweetalert cuando los llame se los agradecería demasiado. Desde ya un cordial saludo para toda la comunidad.

```
If datosempleados.Read Then

                   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "displayalertmessage", "Empleadoalert();", True)

                    If datosVisita.Read Then
                        Session("visitaDni") = TextBoxNumDoc.Text
                        Session("UsuAutori") = usuAuto.Text
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "redirect", "redirect();", True)


                    Else
                        Session("visitaDni") = TextBoxNumDoc.Text
                        Session("UsuAutori") = usuAuto.Text
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, [GetType](), "visita", "Visitaalert();", True)


                    End If
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la contribución. @Alfabravo